# Run Over or Drive Over. Which is correct?

Tags: prepositions

> The old woman was run over by the car infront of her house.
>
> The young man drove his car  over the old woman.

Comment: *run over* means *hit with a vehicle*, but I'm not sure if it works with *drive over.*

Comment: If you say *drive over*, I would understand what you meant, but *run over* is a much more idiomatic way to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct and understandable, but it depends what you want to say.
When speaking in a context (and context is very important in this one) of moving vehicles, if

> *someone* **runs over** *something*

it usually means they have literally driven over *something*, perhaps by accident

> The car **ran over** the squirrel in the road.

would leave a very flattened squirrel. To **hit** *something* would be

> The car **ran into** a tree.
>   The motorcycle **ran into** the back of the bus.
>   There was a chain reaction of cars **running into** each other on the foggy road.

Confusingly, the phrase "I got **run over** by a car" can also mean that a car **ran into** me and my body was displaced or thrown from where I was standing.

To

> **drive over** *something*
>   We had to **drive over** a bumpy road to get to the house.
>   We **drove over** the bridge to get to the other side.

carries more a feeling of intention. So in your examples

> The old woman was **run over** by the car in front of her house.

has a feeling that an accident occurred, whereas

> The young man **drove** his car **over** the old woman.

has a feeling of "vehicular homicide" or intentional "reckless driving".

As an added point, when those two phrases are used outside of moving vehicles, the meanings become very different again

> 1) We have the game on TV, why don't you **run over** and watch it with us?
>   2) We have the game on TV, why don't you **drive over** and watch it with us?

#1 means "get over here quickly" whereas #2 means "come over by car" perhaps quickly

> I'll just **run over** to the store to get some milk *(a quick trip)*
>   I'll **drive over** to the store to get some milk *(usually meaning a longer trip in distance and time)*